# Calling Further Async Methods

Tags: c#, async-await

I've got a situation where I have two async methods that both have the same return type and one calls the other without changing the shape of the data.

```
public async Task<int> Foo() { return 1; }

public async Task<int> Bar() 
{ 
    return await Foo();
}
```

Is there any reason to use `async`/`await` in the `Bar` function or can I simply return the task created by the inner method?

So, for example, is this version of `Bar` more performant? Does it produce one less block?

```
public Task<int> Bar() 
{
    return Foo();
}
```

What's actually happening behind the scenes when async calls are chained in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stephen Cleary wrote about this, [eliding the async](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html).

There are a few issues to watch out for, the one that hit me the most was about exception handling.

I stopped removing it and now usually write `async` all along the chain.

Comment: Interesting article, I didn't know about those implications!